# Facebook SDK PHP vs JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, cordova

In PHP I can do something like:

```
            <p>Or connect with:</p>
            <p>
                <a class="facebook" href="<?php echo $facebook_connect; ?>"></a>
            </p>
```

and `$facebook_connect` would be a variable containing a url with whatever it contains so facebook can launch and either authorize the app, or dump the object of data I am seeking.

However now I am working with phonegap / cordova to port an existing web app to an iOS/Android version of itself. So with that I am wondering is there stuff like the above (mainly the above) that I can use/generate with the JavaScript SDK and use with a link or is there other means/methods? Key reason for this is we have a custom button for facebook that blends in with the app much better than the facebook stock version. So we are hoping to keep using that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into the [facebook javascript sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) particularlay the FB.login method that they have. It make a a pop up window for the user to sign into facebook. There is also the [php sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) if your interested in that.

```
<button type="button" onclick="logginToFaceBook">Login</button> //This will be your button


//possibly in your head or in a JS file
function logginToFacebook(){
 //This was retreive from the page
 FB.login(function(response) {
 if (response.authResponse) {
 console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
 FB.api('/me', function(response) {
   console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
 });
 } else {
 console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
 }
});
```

Don't forget to load the [SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and initialize it with your app id using FB.init.

Comment: Well these parts I know, and i have used the PHP sdk, its the JavaScript one I am trying to familiarize with at this point. Overall I am wondering what my options are as far as customizing the button. Since I have a custom button otherwise on the web for this action and one other I want it to be uniform for my iOS app. But using it in the iOS app via javascript is different than the PHP (for obvious reasons) so Im a little hung up at the moment on it

Comment: @chris correct me if I am wrong. So you have your own button that you want to use. If that is the case then you just need to load the SDK and then when the user clicks the button have it call the FB.login. Does that makes sense. I am gonna add some code to my answer.

Comment: yea, that makes a bit more sense.. I guess working with the PHP version has me thinking a bit more litterel than I should as to how to build it out, rather then working with DOM events and Manipulation through javascript and triggering a function on an event like click.. so in all, thank you

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is, I was gonna wait til I got home to test the case for my luck.. but reviewing it, looks sound enough.